# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON when Fetching Data

Tags: reactjs, redux, frontend, fetch, thunk

I am trying to fetch some data for my project, using Redux Thunk but i get the error which appears in the screenshot.
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dqtm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dqtm.png)

My thunk function
`

```
export const fetchCategoriesStart = () => createAction(CATEGORIES_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_CATEGORIES_START);

export const fetchCategoriesSuccess = (categoriesArray) => createAction(CATEGORIES_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS, categoriesArray);

export const fetchCategoriesFailed = (error) => createAction(CATEGORIES_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_CATEGORIES_FAILED, error);

export const fetchCategoriesAsync = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(fetchCategoriesStart())
  try {
    const response = await fetch('../../menu.json');
    const categoriesArray = await response.json()
    dispatch(fetchCategoriesSuccess(categoriesArray));
  } catch (error){
    dispatch(fetchCategoriesFailed(error));
  }
}
```

`

The component where I dispatch the thunk function:
`

```
import { fetchCategoriesAsync } from "../../store/menu/menu.action";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";
```

```
const Menu = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCategoriesAsync());
  }, [])
```

}`

I tried to fetch some products from a json file using Redux Thunk and I expected the payload to be the array of the products

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)